# How can I integrate 3rd party iOS SDKs into a Forge/Trigger app?

Tags: ios, sdk, trigger.io

I am trying to integrate the TestFlight iOS SDK into my Forge app. Can't seem to find any clear way to do this. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger doesn't yet have a native plugin API to allow for arbitrary native code to be included in your apps.

Our focus has been on keeping the development cycle quick and simple: as native plugins are necessarily much more complex than just writing HTML/CSS/JS, we've not prioritised support for them.

Native plugins are definitely on our roadmap, but at the moment we'd prefer to offer 3rd party SDKs as optional modules to all of our users. If you have a particular need, get in touch at support@trigger.io.

Comment: We have now released Trigger.io native plugins in beta: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/index.html